# Running "New Query" crashes SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-8.1, ssms-2012

SQL Server Management Studio crashes when I try to start a New Query window in  Windows 8.1. I had installed SQL Server Management Studio in windows 8 and today windows OS was updated to 8.1. After update I had opened SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and clicked on new query option then SQL Server Management Studio got crashed.

I referred this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2908806) and tried installing hot fix. Hot fix also throwing error saying 'The update is not applicable to your computer'

Kindly help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you able to perform other functions of SQL Server Management Studio other than starting new query ? like viewing or creating tables.. etc ?

Comment: yeah.. i can able to do...@EmadKhalil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of windows operating system update solved my SQL Server Management Studio 2012 new query crash issue. Hope this may help for someone in future.